# Form is not validated in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, ng-messages

I have this simple form:

```
<form name="assignCtrl.carrierForm">
     <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <label>Company Name</label>
            <input required name="carrierName" ng-model="assignCtrl.searchKeyword">
            <div ng-messages="assignCtrl.carrierForm.carrierName.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">This field is required.</div>
            </div>
     </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container class="md-block">
        <label>Company Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="carrierEmail" ng-model="assignCtrl.companyEmail" required
                               ng-pattern="/^.+@.+\..+$/" minlength="5" maxlength="100"/>
        <div ng-messages="assignCtrl.carrierForm.carrierEmail.$error">
             <div ng-message="required">Email is required.</div>
             <div ng-message-exp="['pattern', 'minlength', 'maxlength']">Please enter a valid email
                                address.
             </div>
        </div>
     </md-input-container>

    <md-button type="submit" ng-disabled="assignCtrl.carrierForm.$invalid" ng-click="assignCtrl.createAndAssign()">Create and Assign
    </md-button>

</form>
```

It is not being validated! `ng-messages` do not appear at all.

`form.$error` is also empty:

```
{{assignCtrl.carrierForm.$error | json }}
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: 1. Try to rename assignCtrl.carrierForm - > assignCtrlCarrierForm (all over the code)
2. Add ng-form direcitve

Comment: @Vitalii can't do 1! As I am using `controllerAs` syntax

Comment: md-input-container is this some kind of directive?

Comment: @Vitalii https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations

Comment: yeah! it is an [angular-material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdInputContainer) directive

Comment: last question :) does input get 'ng-invalid' class when it should be invalid?

Comment: @Vitalii yes it does! I wonder why `ng-messages` won't show

Comment: My idea (possibly bad :D ) is that your ng-message looks to the not THAT scope... What you can try. 1. Create test input out of the directive and check ng-message on it. 
2. Try to use $parent like here:  $parent.assignCtrl.carrierForm.carrierEmail.$error

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found my mistake! In my huge `html` file, the form in the question turned out to be inside another `form` by mistake! That's why, the inner form was being removed! So, I removed the outer form and everything is just fine!